# Office 365 App Development Training

Tags: office-365, office-web-apps, apps-development

Is there a good class out there to get some training on this?
Any recommendation to get into this world?

Comment: I'll convert this to a wiki since it i border line to fit in this community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft virtual academy hosted couple of courses and this one is really good. [Introduction to Office 365 Development](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/introduction-to-office-365-development)
https://github.com/OfficeDev/TrainingContent

You can also watch videos from the Channel 9, [Office 365 Developer Training Kit Labs](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Office-365-Developer-Training-Kit-Labs)

Other than that you can get online paid trainings from [PluralSight](http://www.pluralsight.com/) or [shrepointvideo](http://sharepoint-videos.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out dev.office.com. And note the current offer! There's a "sign up" button in yellow. It's free, and it gives you access to a dev instance of Office 365 for a year!